# PHPUnit, Selenium, and Firefox work, but when I try it with PhantomJS, nothing happens

Tags: php, linux, selenium, phpunit, phantomjs

I have a set of PHPUnit tests that utilize WebDriver and Selenium to run the tests through a browser on my Ubuntu machine.  I got everything working as expected for FireFox, and then tried to simply swap the FireFox WebDriver config for some PhantomJS (1.9.8) WebDriver config. When I use a simple site (google.com), PhantomJS will work, but when I try my dev site, nothing appears to happen within PhantomJS and it eventually fails at my first assertion.  The screenshot has nothing useful (black and white checkerboard).  Whereas if I use google.com, the screenshot is the Google site as expected.

```
    $capabilities = null;

    if($this->testConfig["test.browser"] == "phantomjs"){
        $capabilities = array(
            WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'phantomjs'
            ,'phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0'
            ,WebDriverCapabilityType::ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS => 'true'
            ,WebDriverCapabilityType::PLATFORM => 'LINUX'
            ,WebDriverCapabilityType::JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED => 'true'
            ,'--web-security' => 'no'
            ,'--ignore-ssl-errors' => 'YES'
            ,'--webdriver-loglevel' => 'DEBUG'
            ,'phantomjs.page.settings.webSecurityEnabled' => 'false'
        );
    } else {
        $capabilities = array(WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME => 'firefox');
    }

    $this->webDriver = RemoteWebDriver::create('127.0.0.1:8910', $capabilities, 5000);
    $window = new WebDriverDimension(1440,900);
    $this->webDriver->manage()->window()->setSize($window);
    $webDriver->get($url);

    $webDriver->takeScreenshot('/home/scc/screen1.png');


    $this->webDriver->wait(45, 1000)->until(
        WebDriverExpectedCondition::titleContains($this->testConfig["app.title"])
    );
```

Prior to running the code above, I start the phantomJS server on port 8910

```
scc@ubuntu:/scc/libraries/phantomjs$ phantomjs --webdriver=127.0.0.1:8910
```

PhantomJS is launching GhostDriver...

The problem is that I can get my remote site to work (dev.example.com) through FireFox, but I cannot get it to work through PhantomJS.  I can hit other sites through PhantomJS (google.com), but not my dev.example.com.  I have tried many different settings to get more Debug related log messages from the PhantomJS console, but so far not much of the info has been useful.

> [INFO  - 2016-01-10T23:31:10.717Z] Session [3b277b40-b7f2-11e5-98cd-41d97e3b4946] - page.settings - {"XSSAuditingEnabled":false,"javascriptCanCloseWindows":true,"javascriptCanOpenWindows":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"loadImages":true,"localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled":false,"userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0","webSecurityEnabled":"false"}
>   [INFO  - 2016-01-10T23:31:10.718Z] Session [3b277b40-b7f2-11e5-98cd-41d97e3b4946] - page.customHeaders:  - {}
>   [INFO  - 2016-01-10T23:31:10.718Z] Session [3b277b40-b7f2-11e5-98cd-41d97e3b4946] - Session.negotiatedCapabilities - {"browserName":"phantomjs","version":"1.9.8","driverName":"ghostdriver","driverVersion":"1.1.0","platform":"linux-unknown-32bit","javascriptEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"handlesAlerts":false,"databaseEnabled":false,"locationContextEnabled":false,"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"browserConnectionEnabled":false,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"acceptSslCerts":false,"nativeEvents":true,"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"},"phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0","phantomjs.page.settings.webSecurityEnabled":"false"}
>   [INFO  - 2016-01-10T23:31:10.719Z] SessionManagerReqHand - _postNewSessionCommand - New Session Created: 3b277b40-b7f2-11e5-98cd-41d97e3b4946

I thought maybe it could be an SSL issue to my dev.example.com, but so far it does the exact same thing with http vs. https.  What else could I be doing wrong?  What can I do to help make PhantomJS log more debug info so I can tell where it is failing?

Thanks, 
    Sean